# is there a way to display posts based on priority in the loop in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, web

I want to display post based on priorities and once they are displayed the priority should be lowered so that when next time page is reloaded or refreshed other posts are on the top and those that were already displayed should be at the bottom.

Comment: Please start by giving some code you wrote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

created a meta field 'priority_priority'

```
 <div id="games-container" class="col-md-12">
    <?php 
      $counter = 0;
      $args = array( 'post_type' => 'games', 'posts_per_page' => 10,
             'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
             'order'      => 'DES',
             'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                                'key'     => 'priority_priority'
                            ),
                    ), );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
     if($counter < 2){           
       ?>
       <a href=<?php echo get_post_permalink()?>>
        <div id="mypost" class="col-md-5" style="min-height:400px;">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('large');
         ?>
        </div>
        </a>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <?php
    $counter++;
     } 
    else {?>
    <a href=<?php echo get_post_permalink()?>>
     <div id="mypost" class="col-md-3">
         <!-- post display -->
         <?php the_post_thumbnail('medium'); ?>
        </div>
    </a>
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
       <?php 
       }
     endwhile; 
     wp_reset_postdata();
     ?>
     </div>
```

then used the following code in post template page

```
<?php

     $post_id = get_the_ID();
       $priority = get_post_meta($post_id,'priority_priority',true); 
       if($priority>1)
       {     
          if(!isset($_COOKIE['visitor'.$post_id]))
          {        
               $bool=setcookie('visitor'.$post_id,$post_id,DAY_IN_SECONDS,'/');
               if(count($_COOKIE) > 0)
               {
                    $priority = $priority-1;
                    update_post_meta($post_id,'priority_priority',$priority);
               }
          }

       }
   get_header();
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order the post in random order. It will not display posts in same order after refreshing the page. Try this below code:

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
function my_pre_get_posts($query) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set('orderby', 'rand');
}}
```

Comment: this is cool ! thanx .. but I found another solution.. so using the loop I'll store all the post ids in an array and then I'll retrieve those ids based on priority using priority que. once I get the post ids based on priorities I can display the post in that order.. I hope this will work  :)